SQL Join type needed
I need a little help in determining what Join type/logic I need. I have the below data:

The column DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID is from the table I am Left joining to below (GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS) and I want to match on the rows selected in green, which includes ones that have a value populated, as well as the NULL ones. I also want to exclude rows where GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945 (This is the same rows that contains DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID 61012 and 15000). The problem is that the Left outer join is not filtering out the top row with 61012, and if I switch the join to an INNER JOIN then the logic to exclude GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945 works ok, but then it also filters out the blank rows below, which I still want.
(SELECT ABS(ROUND((SUM(PRIMARY_QUANTITY)/30),2)) AS BURN_RATE, TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID, TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
 TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE , TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID, GL.SEGMENT3
 FROM INV_MATERIAL_TXNS TXN
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_TRANSACTION_TYPES_TL TYPE ON TYPE.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = TXN.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID                                        
LEFT OUTER JOIN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GL ON GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID 
 AND GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945

WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-30)
  AND  TRANSACTION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
  AND TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100002040645155                                
                                                                      
GROUP BY TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID, TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE , TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID
, GL.SEGMENT3  )

If I switch GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS to be an INNER JOIN, then in the results below I filter out the 61012 and 15000 rows as I wanted, but then it also (undersiderly) then filters out the 3 blank rows above as you see below. How can I ensure I am still including the blanks, but filtering out the other two?


Is this correct ON GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID? Shouldn't it relate DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID in both tables?

Yes that is correct, they are just named differently in each table but refer to the same thing.

Perhaps using a Subquery in the WHERE clause to exclude the rows with GL.SEGMENT3 = 945 is the better option than joining to it in the main query?

But there's no CODE_COMBINATION_ID in your screenshot of the GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS table.

Please provide sample input data in text format so we can copy and paste it to test solutions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to format tables in posts.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Edit: disregard my answer. MT0 provided evidence that my query would not yield the correct results
Would it be possible to move the condition to the WHERE statement? For example:
(SELECT ABS(ROUND((SUM(PRIMARY_QUANTITY)/30),2)) AS BURN_RATE, TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID, TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
 TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE , TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID, GL.SEGMENT3
 FROM INV_MATERIAL_TXNS TXN
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_TRANSACTION_TYPES_TL TYPE ON TYPE.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = TXN.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID                                        
LEFT OUTER JOIN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GL ON GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID 
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-30)
  AND  TRANSACTION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
  AND TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100002040645155 
  AND (GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945
        OR GL.SEGMENT3 IS NULL)
-- Edit: the answer by MT0 made me remember to also test for NULL in this case                 
                                                                      
GROUP BY TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID, TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE , TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID
, GL.SEGMENT3  )



This may be wrong as it will match when GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945 or when GL.SEGMENT3 IS NULL AND GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID or when the outer join condition GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID does not match. The middle of those 3 conditions is probably not wanted.

I'm still unable to notice the error... It would be very helpful if the author of the question would provide sample data.
I tried it in a simple W3C example and it seemed to filter out the unwanted values
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left

SELECT *
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
where ShipperID <> 3 
or ShipperID is null
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;



See fiddle for the difference.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for clarifying, @MT0!
I've edited my answer

Add a WHERE filter that checks that either the OUTER JOIN does not match anything or that your condition is matched:
SELECT ABS(ROUND((SUM(PRIMARY_QUANTITY)/30),2)) AS BURN_RATE,
       TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID,
       TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
       TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID,
       GL.SEGMENT3
FROM   INV_MATERIAL_TXNS TXN
       LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_TRANSACTION_TYPES_TL TYPE
       ON TYPE.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = TXN.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID                                        
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GL
       ON     GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID 
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-30)
AND   TRANSACTION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
AND   TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100002040645155                                
AND   (  GL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID IS NULL -- Only happens when OUTER JOIN does not match.
      OR GL.SEGMENT3 <> 945 )                                                                
GROUP BY
       TXN.ORGANIZATION_ID,
       TXN.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       TXN.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
       TXN.DISTRIBUTION_ACCOUNT_ID,
       GL.SEGMENT3  

(Note: Untested as you have not provided any data in a format that can be easily used.)
